# Why when i submit a form for chat app the output comes multiplied by the amount of times i submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, chat

The first time I click submit after i inputted something an li appears, that's good. but when i click on it a second time the output is printed 2 times and a 3 time it is printed 3 times and so on. Why? I only want it to print once each click.

client:

```
var socket = io()
    var name;
    var msg;
    $("#nameForm").on("submit", function(e){
        var name = $(".nameInput").val()
        socket.emit("heres name", name);
        socket.on("outputName", function(data){
            name = data;
            $(".messages").append("<li>" + name +"</li>")
            // $("#nameForm").fadeOut()
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

html:

```
<div class="chatArea">
    <ul class="messages"></ul>
</div>
<form id = "nameForm">
    <input type="text" class="nameInput"><button>Enter Name</button>
</form>
<form id = "msgForm">
    <input class="msgInput" type= "text"></input><button>Enter message</button>
</form>
<script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server is listening on port %d", port)
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

var usernames = {};
var numUsers = 0;
var msg;

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    var addedUser = false;

socket.on("heres name", function(username){
    ++numUsers;
    addedUser = true
    usernames.username = username
    socket.emit("outputName", usernames.username)
})



})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to block submit button on click and wait for response and on response unlock that button.

```js
var socket = io()
var name;
var msg;
$("#nameForm").on("submit", function(e){
    $("#nameForm input[type='submit']").disable();
    var name = $(".nameInput").val()
    socket.emit("heres name", name);
    socket.on("outputName", function(data){
        name = data;
        $(".messages").append("<li>" + name +"</li>");
        $("#nameForm input[type='submit']").enable();
        // $("#nameForm").fadeOut()
    })
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Don't forget to put semicolons on end of your lines!

**UPDATE:**

```js
var socket = io();
var name;
var msg;
socket.on("outputName", function(data){
    name = data;
    $(".messages").append("<li>" + name +"</li>");
    $("#nameForm input[type='submit']").enable();
})
$("#nameForm").on("submit", function(e){
    $("#nameForm input[type='submit']").disable();
    var name = $(".nameInput").val();
    socket.emit("heres name", name);
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your reminder about semicolons . can you please tell me why it outputs like the way it does. why does it seem like the amount of times it is printed depends on the amount of times the form was submitted.  I know you said i have to block the submit button. why does it work like that? I thought that i was using socketio wrong and Im not used to forms.

Comment: ah, I now get what you problem was. You are registering event handler `socket.on("heres name", ...` every time you submit form. Just move your `socket.on` outside of "submit" callback